# Fetching arguments from va_list on arm64, Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, 64-bit

I've strange problem with fetching argument from va_list which works perfectly on simulator, problem begins when the same code is run on device (iPhone 6s) looks like arm64 doesn't support this well. Any ideas?

```
va_start(arguments, self_);
id arg = va_arg(arguments, id);
// arg is NULL
va_end(arguments);
```

Edit:

On simulator get correct arg object (NSString *) however when the same code run on device (iPhone 6s) the same arg object is always NULL.

```
...^(id self_, SEL cmd_, ....) {

.....

va_list arguments;
va_start(arguments, cmd_);

NSUInteger arg_count = [methodSignature numberOfArguments];
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < arg_count - 2; i++ ) {

    NSUInteger idx = i+2;
    const char *type = [methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:idx];

    if (strcmp(@encode(id), type) == 0) {
        id arg = va_arg(arguments, id);
        [invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:idx];
    }
}
va_end(arguments);
```

Comment: What is `id` ..? What is a strange problem? Post a minimal example.

Comment: For minimal example, we need a caller as well; however based on that `if`, I'd be inclined to believe that you could be missing arguments. Bear in mind that vararg handing on amd64 is very different from x64, so simulator vs. hardware is chalk vs cheese.

Comment: access to the same arguments list on simulator and arm7v device, returns the object (id type) otherwise for iPhone 6s (arm64) it's a plain pointer, which crashes on call invokeWithTarget

Answer (score 1):

Basic method is swizzled by custom block which handles new implementation where as argument is passing varargs:

```
void (*actionSelectorImplementationBlock) = ^(id self_, ...) {
// ...... Creating Invocation etc....

va_list arguments;
va_start(arguments, self_);
NSUInteger arg_count = [methodSignature numberOfArguments];
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < arg_count - 2; i++ ) {

    NSUInteger idx = i+2;
    const char *type = [methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:idx];

    id arg = va_arg(arguments, id);
    [invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:idx];
}
va_end(arguments);
// Invoke NSInvocatin
} 

IMP newImplementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(actionSelectorImplementationBlock);
method_setImplementation(originalMethod, newImplementation);
```

Swizzled method:

```
- (void)test:(NSNumber *)t test2:(NSString *)string;
```